# Icons with border, next to each others with border hover effect

Tags: html, css, icons, border

I have small obstacle. I would like to have icons with border next to each other in one line, but with hover effect that change the icons border color.

When I make the hover effect with border 2px solid green, first two icons are moving left by 2 px. How to get the hover effect border color different all around the one icon.

Icons are from font awesome, here are not visible.

```css
span{
  border: 2px solid red;
  &:nth-child(1),
  &:nth-child(2) {
      border-right: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span>
    <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </span>
  <span>PL</span>
  <span id="over-menu-open">
    <i  class="fa fa-long-arrow-up " aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Don’t use different border widths, but a transparent border color. Or use `outline` instead of border, that doesn’t affect element dimensions and positions at all.

Comment: Here's a [pen with Font Awesome loaded from a CDN](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/xdVxEL). And Scss + normalize + Autoprefixer. You can add your hover effect and relevant styles from there and fork it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got you right, but you could try this:

```
span {
  border: 2px solid red;

  & + & {
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

The above sets the border colour to transparent instead of removing it, thus the elements will not jump.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `span:hover + span` selector to remove the left border of the next `span`.

```css
span {
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  padding: 1px;
}

span:last-child {
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

span:hover {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

span:hover + span {
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>PL</span><span id="over-menu-open"><i  class="fa fa-long-arrow-up " aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
```

Comment: Thank you Shiva! It is working. I don't know but it wasn't working while I was using Saas styles, but with normal css it is working. Also the transition slower effect interrupted in this. But when I canceled the transition effect the effect is nice and visible :)

Comment: So you validate the other answer. I don't understand. ;)